# use static var, it will block, how to explain this situation

Tags: c++

```
int Test(int i)
{
    i--;
    if(i <= 0 || i > 2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        static int y = Test(i);
        return (y+1);
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << Test(3);
    return 0;
}
```

when run to Test(i), it will block.
how to explain this situation?

Comment: A debugger might help.

Comment: You're trying to initialize `y` with a value that depends on the value of `y`. What do you expect to happen? That `y` would be initialized by the last recursion rather than the first?

Comment: your specific issue aside, `Test(i)` calling `Test(i)` already means that there is an inifinite recursion and your logic is flawed

Comment: I think the easiest explanation is:  C++ is not a nanny language.  It gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot, with enough left over to do the all rigging of a small schooner.  C++ expects the developer to know what their doing, and to not provide ill-formed code causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour if during initialization of a static variable, the code reaches the initialization block again.

Which happens for `Test(3)` -> `y=Test(2)`->`y=Test(1)`.

Comment: Is it an infinite loop or a deadlock?

Comment: @xiangyuhaoaizcm It is undefined behaviour, anything can happen. It might be deadlock since static initialization must be thread-safe so if the compiler uses some form of non-reentrant mutex, it will deadlock. But as I said, it is not defined what must happen.